# Как правильно построить графически бинарное дерево n глубины

Tags: c#

Не могу найти примера с корректным построением бинарного дерева. Если не использовать глубину, а просто -30 и +30 выводить, то на 2 глубине вершины сливаются, но даже зная глубину криво выводит, подскажите как сделать:

```
private static List<Vector2> GetGrafTree(Node<double> currentNode)
{
    if (currentNode.depth == 1)
        dots.Add(new Vector2(currentNode.Element, (Program.getForm.Width / 2), 10, 1)); // добавить корень дерева
    int index = dots.FindLastIndex(elem => (elem.Value == currentNode.Element));  // находим вышестоящий элемент
    //пока не конец левого поддерева
    if (currentNode.Left != null)
    {
        int x = dots[index].X - (30 * currentNode.depth);
        int y = dots[index].Y + 40;
        string name = currentNode.Element.ToString() + "&" + currentNode.Left.Element.ToString();
        //lines.Add(new Line(name, dots[index].X+5, dots[index].Y+25, x+15, y));
        dots.Add(new Vector2(currentNode.Left.Element, x, y, currentNode.Left.depth)); // позиция левого элемента дерева
        GetGrafTree(currentNode.Left); // следующий левый элемент 
    }
    //пока не конец правого поддерева
    if (currentNode.Right != null)
    {
        int x = dots[index].X + (30 * currentNode.depth);
        int y = dots[index].Y + 40;
        string name = currentNode.Element.ToString() + "&" + currentNode.Right.Element.ToString();
        //lines.Add(new Line(name, dots[index].X+25, dots[index].Y+25, x+15, y));
        dots.Add(new Vector2(currentNode.Right.Element, x, y, currentNode.Right.depth)); // позиция правого элемента дерева
        GetGrafTree(currentNode.Right); // следующий правый элемент 
    }
    return dots;
}
```

Comment: Я не очень понял, вам нужно, чтобы дерево выводилось слева направо (как в проводнике) или сверху вниз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несколько дней ломал голову над максимально красивой визуализацией бинарного дерева.
Остановился на следующем способе:

1. Добавляем в класс узла поле с уровнем узла.
2. В реализации метода добавления нового узла дописываем строки для инициализации нового поля.
3. Реализуем рекурсивный метод симметричного обхода. По мере обхода добавляем к X-су нужное для отступа расстояние, а Y будет равен уровню узла умноженному на отступ по Y-ку.

Приведу пример на плюсах(код для движка SFML):

```
template<class T>
void STree<T>::InOrder(){

static sf::Vector2f pos;

if (this->isRoot){
    pos = sf::Vector2f(0,0);
    pos.x -= getHeight() * 150;
 }

if(left) left->InOrder();

node_box->setNewPosition(sf::Vector2f(pos.x, level * 200));
pos.x += 150;

if(right) right->InOrder();

 }
```

У меня получилось вот такое дерево:

[image: У меня получилось вот такое дерево:]

Правда пока без соединяющих линий. Но добавить не сложно =)

Comment: Вот уж не думал, что такую древность поднимут, но всё же благодарю за ваш способ :)

Answer (score 1):

Вы начинаете строить с корня, но вы не знаете на этот момент реальную высоту, отсюда и проблемы с наложением. Вам нужно для начала определить высоту дерева, затем вычислить расстояние между вершинами на каждом ярусе.

Псевдокод для определения высоты:

```
int Высота(Вершина вершина)
{
    if (вершина == null) return -1;
    return 1 + Max(Высота(вершина.ЛевыйПотомок), Высота(вершина.ПравыйПотомок));
}
```

Когда у вас есть высота дерева `высотаДерева` и вы задались расстоянием между вершинами на самом верху `расстояниеМеждуВершинами`, просто определяем расстояние на текущем ярусе примерно так: `2 ^ (высотаДерева - номерЯруса) * расстояниеМеждуВершинами`

---

Другой вариант, если ваш GUI-фреймворк справляется с векторной графикой (умеет ее произвольно растягивать), просто примите расстояние на верхнем ярусе равное 1, а на каждом следующем уровне уменьшайте его в 2 раза.

Пример как это могло бы выглядеть в WPF:

```
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas Name="TreeCanvas"/>
    </Viewbox>
```

Строим:

```
void DrawTree(Node node, double x, double y, double dx, double dy)
{
    if (node == null) return;
    var e = new Ellipse
    {
        Width = 5,
        Height = 5,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
    };
    TreeCanvas.Children.Add(e);
    Canvas.SetLeft(e, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(e, y);
    DrawTree(node.Left, x - dx, y + dy, dx / 2, dy);
    DrawTree(node.Right, x + dx, y + dy, dx / 2, dy);
}
```

Надо лишь вызвать этот метод и передать ему корень дерева:

```
DrawTree(tree, 100, 0, 50, 50);
```

Ну и задать размеры канвасу (вьюбокс растянет его на всё окно, нам лишь надо чтобы уместились все узлы):

```
TreeCanvas.Height = 2 * 100 + 2 * 5;
TreeCanvas.Width = 2 * 100 + 2 * 5;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72033/discussion-on-answer-by--nop------).

Comment: Я в чате вам написал, но построить дерево как у вас я хз как (

Answer (score 0):

Приведу небольшой пример для вывода через консоль. Для GUI код будет аналогичен. Определяем узел дерева:

```
class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public TreeNode Left { get; set; }

    public TreeNode Right { get; set; }
}
```

Пишем метод для печати дерева на экран:

```
    static void Print(TreeNode node, int y, int left, int right)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var x = left + (right - left) / 2;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(node.Value);

        Print(node?.Left, y + 1, left, x);
        Print(node?.Right, y + 1, x, right);
    }
```

Метод принимает следующие аргументы:

- node - очередной узел
- y - отступ сверху для вывода текущего узла
- left - левая граница для вывода текущего узла
- right - правая граница для вывода текущего узла

Идея заключается в том, что у нас есть строго определенная высота узла, которая увеличивается для потомков этого узла, и границы по-горизонтали. Сам узел выводится ровно посередине этой границы. Левый потомок выводится на следующей строке с ограничением правой границы, правый - с ограничением левой границы.

Собственно, остается только вызвать этот метод для корня дерева:

```
var root = CreateTree();
Print(root, 0, 0, Console.WindowWidth);
```

Как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: увы, метод консоли не подходит для графического вывода

Comment: @ДенисМашанов, почему не подходит? x, y - координаты середины примитива для вывода узла. Разве что конструкцию `y + 1` нужно будет заменить на `y + height`, где height - высота одной строки дерева.

Comment: ну у меня чуть другая конструкция, похожая, но другая.

Comment: int x = dots[index].X - (20 * (1 << (maxDepth - currentNode.Left.depth)));
int y = dots[index].Y + 60;